# How to send Redux-Store to multiple Components?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

```
export const StoreSender= connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps,
  mergeProps,
)(StoreRec1, StoreRec2);
```

How can I do this? Note that I have returns from both mapStateToProps and mapDispatchToProps.

StoreRec1 and StoreRec2 are two different components to which I want to send data.

Comment: Consider wrapping both of them separately. If it's too repetitive, consider using a HOC (higher order component), render props or any other reusability technique.

Comment: You can use connect separately for both the components